# Error when scheduling a task through CMD: the parameter is incorrect

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a task that would delete the temp files on Windows, but I am getting an error message that says `ERROR: the parameter is incorrect`. No error code is provided.

The code I am trying to use is the following:

`SCHTASKS /create /sc daily /tn "C:\Users\user\Documents\scheduled_scripts\del_temp_files" /tr "C:\Users\user\Documents\scheduled_scripts\del_temp_files.cmd" /st 00:00`

Unfortunately, I am not managing to spot the problem that is triggering the error. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You need specify a program to run your non executable CMD file. Type `cmd /?`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am not sure how to do what you said,. I repeated the code that was provided at [Windows Central site](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-task-using-task-scheduler-command-prompt): `SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN "FOLDERPATH\TASKNAME" /TR "C:\SOURCE\FOLDER\APP-OR-SCRIPT" /ST HH:MM``. The article also state that the /tr parameter may receive either an .exe file or a custom script.  How may I specify a program to execute my .cmd  file using that structure?.

Comment: Type ` CMD /?`.

Comment: Just use a name there is no need to to use a path, `/tn del_temp_files`.